# Find a Möbius transformation $g$ such that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Let $f$ be a function with domain $D= ${$z \in \mathbb C$: $|z| < 8$} given by
$$ f(z) =\sum_{n≥0}\dfrac{i^nz^n}{8^n}. $$

Find a Möbius transformation $g$ such that $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z \in D$. Calculate $f(i)$ and $f'(0)$.

Comment: this is a geometric series

Comment: Well it is what it is, I just need some help please

Comment: $f(z)$ is convergent therefore $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{iz}{8}}=\frac{0\cdot z+8}{-i\cdot z+8}=:g(x)$. Is this what you mean ?

Comment: @Pstar007 You know, Hagen gave you the key to the problem and you just waved it off.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how it helps, really not my strong point. Could you please elaborate?